# Can document.addEventListener("Mousemove") decrease perfromance in WEBGL?

Tags: javascript, webgl

I'm new to WebGL, and I was trying to make a game to learn it, so I faced this question...
I heard that WebGL uses GPU and the JavaScript without WebGL uses CPU, and I heard which using `document.getElementByID` or `document.addEventListener` in JavaScript uses CPU... 
so I was wondering how to get mouse position in WebGL code ? Is using this kind of code okay?

```
document.addEventListener("mousemove" , function (event) {x=event.PageX;y=event.PageY};
```

and then use x and y in the gameLoop function which is called by requestAnimitionFrame.

I mean would it be a problem because the above code uses CPU while the WebGL uses GPU...?

As I said I'm completely new, so my question may be silly **but what is the best way to get mouse position in WebGL?**

**and also Is using  `document.getElementByID` in WebGL code a bad Idea?**

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GPU used for some hard mathematics calculations, because they could be done faster on it. But in your case you don't do any mathematics, you just store some data from one variable to another, it can't be done by GPU, in any case it would be done by CPU and it's normal because because only CPU can do it.

And it's ok, don't worry.

Comment: thanks a lot. you mean it wont interrupt my mathematics calculations in gameloop function ? WebGL it self understand what to do ? 
thanks a lot. I'm new and I was worry to do things not efficiently. 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

It can reduce the speed, if you do raycasting inside the function of the event listener and you have many active objects for raycasting in WebGL